# Iterate over a list of dataframes and get a subset of each dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, iteration

I have a list of dataframes (mylist) and i want to iterate over them and get all the rows from each dataframe that in a specific column don't have some values("upstream" or "downstream")!I would like to return the subsets (for the rest of the values) of dataframes back to the list!
For the moment i am doing that:

```
mylist<- lapply(mylist, function(df){
  if (df$column != "upstream" | "downstream"){
     mylist <- df
  }
})
```

Which gives the following error:

```
Error in df$insideFeature : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

Thanks you in advance for any help provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PeterDee also noted: you are using `|` incorrectly. Use `%in%` to do this as follows

```
myfun <- function(df, words) {
  good_col <- which(! df$column %in% words)
  df[good_col,]
}
```

and then

```
lapply(mylist, myfun, c("upstream", "downstream"))
```

Comment: I basically managed to do it that way but thanks for your answer!        `for (i in 1:length(mylist)){
 mylist[[i]]<- subset(mylist[[i]],mylist[[i]]$column != "upstream" & mylist[[i]]$column !="downstream")
}`