# How to subset rows when looping through a list of data.tables?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm working with a large number of data.tables in R. I have put the data.tables in a list, like the example below:

```
dt1 <- data.table(v1 = c("a","a","a"), v2 = 1:3)
dt2 <- data.table(v1 = c("notes","a","a"), v2 = 1:3)
dt3 <- data.table(v1 = c("notes","a","a"), v2 = 1:3)

dt_list <- list(dt1, dt2, dt3)
```

I would like to perform a set of operations on each data.table in the list. For example, removing rows with "notes" in v1, and adding new columns.

Column operations work as I expected (although a new data.table, dt, appears in my environment):

```
for (dt in dt_list) {
  dt <- dt[, newvar := "new"]
} 

dt2
          v1 v2 newvar
    1: notes  1    new
    2:     a  2    new
    3:     a  3    new
```

However, row operations don't appear to edit the data.tables in the same way:

```
for (dt in dt_list) {
  dt <- dt[v1 != "notes", ]
}

dt2
          v1 v2 newvar
    1: notes  1    new
    2:     a  2    new
    3:     a  3    new
```

The code within the for loop does work for a single data.table, so the problem appears to arise from the use of for and/or list:

```
dt2 <- dt2[v1 != "notes"]
dt2
       v1 v2 newvar
    1:  a  2    new
    2:  a  3    new
```

I have tested this for other row operations and faced the same problem. Is there a way that I can remove the rows that contain "notes" in v1 for all data.tables in the list?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `lapply(dt_list, function(dt) dt[v1 != "notes"])`

Comment: In addition `lapply(dt_list, function(x) x[v1 != "notes"][, newvar := "new"])`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583287/iterate-over-a-list-of-dataframes-and-get-a-subset-of-each-dataframe-in-r

Comment: Operations will be a lot less cumbersome if you combine the tables `DT = rbindlist(dt_list, id="dt_num")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `data.table` package allows you to change the values of objects by reference using the `set` function or `:=` operator. The assignment operator `<-` has no such default behaviour. So if you replaced your first loop with:

```
for (dt in dt_list) {
  dt[, newvar := "new"]
}
```

It would have the same effect. You change `dt` just by using `:=`. On the other hand, if you don't use it, changes will not be reflected in your original data. For now, I don't believe you can delete or subset rows by reference using `data.table`, so you need to create a new list as suggested by @jogo or @markus

```
dt_list2<-lapply(dt_list, function(dt) dt[v1 != "notes"])
```